# QuillJS wrap Image in a div

Tags: javascript, quill

I want to be able to paste images but with an added wrapper to it. Code I currently have is similar to this [demo](https://quilljs.com/playground/). However, this produces

```
<p><img src="base64Value" /></p>
```

What I want is something like

```
<p><div class="custom-wrapper"><img src="base64Value"/></div></p>
```